# Returning char* from dllexported function

Tags: c++, c, dllexport

I'm creating a DLL which will be used by some external exe file. One of the exposed function is

```
...
char *current_version = "1.1";
...

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) char* version(){ 
  return current_version;
}
```

Because the current version is used in multiple places I created the current_version variable. Will caller of the version function be able to change the content of current_version variable ? (I expect he'll).

If I'll change the code to:

```
...
const char *current_version = "1.1"; //this is preferable 
...

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) char* version(){ 
  char local_copy[100] = make_local_copy(current_version);
  return *local_copy;
}
```

will the local_copy variable be disposed after execution of the version function finishes (and in this case returned pointer will point at some random data) ? If so, what is the best way to return a pointer to const char* ?

Comment: what does make_local_copy do? shallow copy or deep copy?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should always avoid returning `char*`. Do `extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void version(char* buffer, int buffer_len){ 
  strncpy(buffer, current_version, buffer_len);
}`

Comment: do `char local_copy[100] = make_local_copy(current_version);` even compile?

Comment: Why would the user of the DLL want to change the version number reported by the DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will caller of the version function be able to change the content of current_version variable ?

This is UB, so the actual behavior depends on implementation. There is a good chance that caller indeed could change this constant. In some implementations, string literals are stored in read-only memory, so attempting to write to it through a non-const pointer will throw a runtime error instead.

> will the local_copy variable be disposed after execution of the version function finishes

Yes.

> (and in this case returned pointer will point at some random data) ?

It will, in most implementations, point to an area of stack. Writing to it would corrupt program execution flow.

> If so, what is the best way to return a pointer to const char* ?

There is no good way to do that in C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void version(char* buffer, int* len)
    {
     if (buffer == NULL || *len <= 0)
         {
          char local_copy[100] = make_local_copy(current_version);
          *len = strlen (local_copy);
          return;
         }

     char local_copy[100] = make_local_copy(current_version);
     *len = strlen (local_copy);
     strcpy_s(buffer, *len, local_copy);
     return;
    }
```

This should be a good starting point. There may be bugs and also I recommend you use wchar instead of char. This is my best guess at a safe function with memory issues. User makes the first call to determine length required. dynamically allocate buffer in calling function and then call this method again. Or allocate memory and assign length if you already know the size of the buffer and the length, you will need to call this function just once.

Comment: Why are you making a local copy of a constant?  You don't need it.

Comment: I agree, I am not sure why @orwe has it in his code. I thought that was some core piece of logic he needed so I did not touch that part.

Comment: Your solution is correct but you changed the API (I can't do this)

Answer (score 0):

1. About the questions, I agree with @Agent_L.
2. About the solution, I think you can use a static char array as a buffer. Just as follows:

```c
static char local_copy[64];
static char current_version[] = "1.1";

char *version() {
  strcpy(local_copy, current_version);
  return local_copy;
}
```

Then you don't need to worry about disposing of `local_copy`.

Comment: Agree but assuming I'll have 20 variables (app_name, kernel_version, ...) this will lead to a bigger amount of variables.